# How to select an item in a ListBox based on the order of the items as they appear on screen

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

My WPF application has a `ListBox` in it.  The `ListBox's` `ItemsSource` property is set to a collection of objects I have defined.  These all descend from `UserControl`.

I need to loop over the items in the `ListBox` in the order that they appear on screen.  I believe I can do this by looping over the `ListBox's` `Items` collection.

I believe that the objects inthis collection are of type `ListBoxItem`.  How do I get at the objects of my type from the `ListBoxItem`?  In other words, how do I get at the instance of my class descended from `UserControl` from the `ListBoxItem`?

EDIT:

Additional information I should have included in the first place:

I need to loop over the `Items` in the order that they appear in the `ListBox` so I can select the one closest to the top that matches a particular condition.  After I find the one I'm interested in, I need to select it.  It's a single select `ListBox`, so only one item at a time will be selected.

So, my question really is:  How do I select the Item?

Not that it matters, but the reason my type descends from `UserControl` is because it contains a number of controls that need to be diplayed in the `ListBox` for each item.

Comment: The question title is not descriptive of the problem *at all*, please change it and leave out tags, they do *not* belong there.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be a tag, it was supposed to let the reader know I wasn't talking about a WinForms ListBox.

Comment: That is exactly what a tag is, it categorizes. The tag section serves that purpose just fine, the vast majority of people who use this site either look at the tags, or browse by tag anyway so you do not need to place them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to loop over the items in the `Items` collection in reverse order.  I'm not sure why this is, I thought that the `Items` collection held everything in the order they appear on screen.  Perhaps it's because the ListBox is sorted in descending order on a `DateTime` property of the underlying data?

In any case, since I had to loop backwards, I ended up having to write a `for` loop that started at the end of the collection and worked its way forwards.  Since I now had the index of the item I wanted to select, it was easy to just set `ListBox.SelectedIndex` to that index.

Comment: Instead of looping in reverse order you could also simply use [LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548915.aspx) instead of FirstOrDefault in the same way i described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Items` are exactly what you set them or the `ItemsSource` to (and it should usually be data objects, not `UserControls`), so you just need to cast them to your type.

> Not that it matters, but the reason my type descends from UserControl is because it contains a number of controls that need to be diplayed in the ListBox for each item.

That is *not* a good reason. In WPF you should use data items and use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) to display the data with the respective controls.

Also to select a given item the data item should have an `IsSelected` property which then can be bound in the [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to the [`ListBoxItem.IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected.aspx) property.

If you then set the `IsSelected` to `true` on the item the respective `ListBoxItem` should be selected as well (you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on the item).

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I didn't state my question correctly.  Please read my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply select the first item that matches the condition:

```
Func<ItemType, bool> match =
    item =>
    {
        return ...; // a bool that indicates if the condition is matched
    };

listBox.SelectedItem = listBox.Items.Cast<ItemType>().FirstOrDefault(match);
```